Print tickets with ASP.NET Core or js
I have to print a ticket. It is important to ensure that each ticket is printed only once.
I have created a view where the image of the tickets is created and finally printed with javascript. The browser is in kiosk mode and the user is not asked the question for printing and it is printed directly
Sometimes printing is not done or I can't make sure of the printing status. How can I have a more reliable print?
When the ticket page is loaded and printed with JavaScript, a field in the database is changed so that it cannot be printed twice. But sometimes the printout is not sent or it is not printed, but it is stored in the database after it was printed, and this is a problem
For printing, I use this code:
   window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
       window.print();
   });

